# Docker mount file default permissions 777 and MariaDB complaining about world-writable (mounted) config file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

My service definition, where `mariadb.cnf` is mounted on `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/80-app.cnf`:

```yml
db:
    image: mariadb:10.11
    volumes:
        - ./mariadb.cnf:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/80-app.cnf:ro
```

On startup:

> 2023-06-14 18:27:16 Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/80-app.cnf' is ignored.

I know exactly what's happening, Docker is mouting my file with 777 permission:

```txt
# ls -la /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun 14 18:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun  9 23:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   46 Jun  9 23:30 05-skipcache.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  575 Jun  5 19:14 50-client.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  231 Jun  5 19:14 50-mysql-clients.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  927 Jun  5 19:14 50-mysqld_safe.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3584 Jun  9 23:30 50-server.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  570 Jun  5 19:14 60-galera.cnf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  167 Jun 14 16:39 80-app.cnf
```

I can remove the `ro` option, `chmod 644 /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/80-app.cnf`, restart the container, re-add `ro` option, it works.

**The problem is that anyone using my project have to to this the first time. Do I have any option?**

I'm seriously thinking about adding in my `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

chmod 644 /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*-app.cnf
```

But I really hope there is a better solution.

Comment: I tried with podman and it preserves the unix permissions.  Maybe you could mount a directory instead of a file? Note the [official mount point](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) is `/etc/mysql/conf.d`. Happy to take an improvement to [the implementation](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.6/mysys/my_default.c#L636) that does `access(file, W_OK)` that checks for RO filesystems (and immutable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed so that **read only** mounts of configuration files are considered to have the same protection and will be read/processed.

Fixed for versions 10.4.31, 10.5.22, 10.6.15, 10.9.8, 10.10.6, 10.11.5, 11.0.3, 11.1.2, 11.2.1 and above.

was: bug report [MDEV-27038](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27038) / server patch [#2669](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/2669)

Comment: Thanks for the PR. I'm quite sure that Docker said something like "the application itself should handle the 777 permission in some way", i.e. they will never allow to mount files with custom permission, at least I think (I've a basic understanding of containers). Let's see.

Comment: Sounds about right. There's so many ways and Docker adding options just make more to test coverage for every application. Keeping a few basic behaviours is all right, even if we need to change some very old assumptions.

Comment: I tested the PR on github. Btw you said "/etc/mysql/conf.d" is the official mount point, but what's loading order then? Will "/etc/mysql/conf.d" be sourced after /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/ or before? I just want to make sure my cnf has higher priority...

Comment: Yes "/etc/mysql/conf.d" last and has priority and I made sure it does. `podman run --rm mariadb:10.11 cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Its also the one guaranteed for future compatibility.